# Excess output from fabric.api.run

Tags: python, fabric

When running a command through fabric.api.run, how do I capture the output of *only* the command that I am running on the remote server?

Any output that results from the system bash_profile file is being captured by fabrics output as well.

Not exactly sure what to do in this case.

```
from fabric.api import env, run
env.host_string = "hostname"

def run_a_thing():
    output = run("find /some/files/somewhere")
    return output

the_files_I_want = run_a_thing()

the_files_I_want

[hostname] run: find /some/files/somewhere  
**[hostname] out: Module slurm/15.08.1 loaded**   
**[hostname] out:**   
[hostname] out: file1...  
[hostname] out: file2...
```

The undesired output is the starred lines above. Modules are loaded automatically by the administrators (slurm, in this case), and the output from the module load command appears with the output of the command that I am trying to run.

Using *output.stdout*, since output is actually a wrapper class, does not work. It returns exactly the same thing, since this is all stdout.

So, ideas to fix this specific problem, ideas for a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'll share the workaround that I used for the time being. If anyone has another way of doing it, please share.

From:

```
def do_thing(path):
    command = "find {}".format(path)
    return run(command).stdout.splitlines()
```

To:

```
def do_thing(path):
    command = "find {}".format(path)
    background = run("").stdout.splitlines()
    output = run(command).stdout.splitlines()
    return [x for x in output if x not in background]
```

And, since random whitespace seems to be an issue with the output:

```
def do_thing(path):
    command = "find {}".format(path)
    background = run("").stdout.splitlines()
    output = run(command).stdout.splitlines()
    desired_output = []

    for line in output:
        for unwanted_line in background:
            if not re.search(unwanted_line.strip(), line):
                desired_output += [line]

    return desired_output
```